# Can't access Aliexpress functions in top.api

Tags: python, api, aliexpress

I'm just started to search Aliexpress-API documentation. In there: [Developers.aliexpress](https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=39634&docType=2) , Im coding in **python** and need to import **AliexpressSolutionProductPostRequest** from **top.api** but it fails.

I installed top lib on Windows like that: python -m pip install top
Reinstalled twice but it fails. Its official website and fails. I can't figure it out.

```
AttributeError: module 'top.api' has no attribute 'AliexpressSolutionProductPostRequest'
```

This library has diffrent functions for **Alibaba** , **not for aliexpres**. Any suggestion for fix that ? Actually i can't find top library's offical documentation too.Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Okey. I found this library for fix that error. We need to install [aliexpress-sdk](https://github.com/bayborodin/aliexpress-sdk):

```
pip install aliexpress-sdk
```

or (for pre-release):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/bayborodin/aliexpress-sdk
```

Now I can import Aliexpress modules which are in [Aliexpress API Documentation](https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=43561&docType=2).

Example module import for aliexpress:

```
from aliexpress.api import AliexpressSolutionProductPostRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

I just learned offical way to do that.

After create an app on [Aliexpress Console](https://developers.aliexpress.com/en), you can generate API SDK for Python. In there you can find top library's functions which are in [Aliexpress API Documentation](https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=43561&docType=2). So we need to create App first, once accepted , we can do all these stuff.